# Mi pregunta sobre Base da Datos

Tags: sql

hola estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar bases de datos pero nose que pasa que cuando trato de insertar datos me da error.

```
CREATE DATABASE prueba;
use prueba;
CREATE TABLE provedores (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
numero int,
nombre varchar(50),
status_ varchar(50),
ciudad  varchar(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO provedores (numero, nombre, status_, ciudad) VALUES ('S1','Julio Sanchez',1,'Londres');
```

Comment: Primero que nada, ¿Cuál es el error? La etiqueta no debería ser base de datos, sino algo más específico. Capaz eso es pl o maria o solo tú vayas a saber qué. Otro aspecto a tener en cuenta, que el código tiene un formato para que quede legible para aquellos que entren en tu pregunta. Para finalizar, si un campo como número es declarado `int` , ¿Por qué harías algo como querer asignarle un valor de tipo texto como lo es **'S1'**?

Comment: Además de lo comentado antes, intenta añadir títulos descriptivos del problema a tus mensajes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observa que estás intentando insertar texto (`'S1'`) en una columna que solo acepta números enteros (`numero`).

Adicionalmente, es aconsejable que, al momento de formular tu pregunta, utilices etiquetas que le indiquen a la comunidad de Stack Overflow qué manejador de base de datos estás utilizando, así como también es recomendable que hagas uso de las herramientas de edición para aplicar formato y estilo a los códigos que incluyas en tu pregunta antes de publicarla.